# How can I insert a word into a table after checking it against another table?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables: `searches` and `commonWords`. Given user input Q, if Q is not found in `commonWords`, I want to insert it into `searches`.

To be honest I'm just completely confused how I would do this. How can I combine INSERT INTO with the whole SELECT .. WHERE thing?

I know I can do it with two queries:

```
$db->query('SELECT * FROM commonWords WHERE word = ?', $q);
if ($db->affectedRows() > 0)
  $db->query('INSERT INTO searches (search) VALUES (?)', $q);
```

However, I would like to confine this operation to one query.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this if you want to insert a row that exisists in commonWords

```
insert into searches (search) select word from commonWords where word = ?
```

but you have to be carefull because you have to set a unique index for searches.search
if not you could insert multiple rows of the same value

if you want insert a non existing word into searches, then you have to try this

```
$db->query('insert into searches (search) select case when count(word) = 0 then \'?\' else NULL end as word from commonWords where word = ?', $q);
```

Comment: "Given user input Q, if Q is not found in commonWords" --- I thought he need to insert a row to `searches` when **there is no** row in `commonWords`

Comment: Yes, i read that but his statement `if ($db->affectedRows() > 0)` is telling a other storry ... i edited my answer and now you have 2 solutions ;-)

Comment: inserting null can cause error (in case that he has not null constraint) or a lot of garbage rows otherwise

Comment: thats why he has to set a unique index for searches.search ;-)